# FakeRedis exception - FakeSocket does not have fileno() method

Tags: python-3.x, windows, redis

I'm switching a Python project from 2.7.x to 3.7.x, running on Windows 10, and have hit an issue with FakeRedis. I have a RedisCache class which looks like this:

```
class RedisCache(object):
    def __init__(self, connection_info, is_testing):
        if is_testing:
            import fakeredis
            self.conn = fakeredis.FakeStrictRedis()
        else:
            self.conn = redis.StrictRedis(host=connection_info['host'], port=connection_info['port'], db=0)

def get(self, key_name, default=None):
    return self.conn.get(key_name)
```

When running my tests the connection is created as an instance of FakeStrictRedis, then when calling 'get' the code eventually calls into 'redis.SelectSelector.check_is_ready_for_command', which then calls 'select.select', passing in an instance of 'fakeredis._server.FakeSocket'.

```
def check_is_ready_for_command(self, timeout):
    """
    Return True if the socket is ready to send a command,
    otherwise False.
    """
    r, w, e = select.select([self.sock], [self.sock], [self.sock],
                            timeout)
    return bool(w and not r and not e)
```

I then get the following callstack on the call to 'select.select':

```
\core\rediscache.py                         line 41, in get                           s = self.conn.get(key_name)
\env\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py      line 1264, in get                         return self.execute_command(\'GET\', name)
\env\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py      line 772, in execute_command              connection = pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
\env\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py  line 999, in get_connection               if not connection.is_ready_for_command():  
\env\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py  line 632, in is_ready_for_command         return self._selector.is_ready_for_command() 
\env\lib\site-packages\redis\selector.py    line 43, in is_ready_for_command          return self.check_is_ready_for_command(timeout)
\env\lib\site-packages\redis\selector.py    line 104, in check_is_ready_for_command   timeout) 
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.
```

The issue is that FakeSocket doesn't have a fileno() method, so it's unclear how this is supposed to work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally after investigating this for two days I ask the question and then immediately find the answer. fakeredis isn't compatible with redis version 3.2, downgrading to 3.0.1 fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, all my tests are broken due to this issue.

Comment: fakeredis now supports latest redis version and latest python version